# Docker container changes not reflected in the web browser

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, docker-volume, docker-container

Docker version 20.10.21

I have a react frontend, node backend and mongo database app and I want to use docker volume to share the source code. When I mount the backend, changes are automatically reflected in the container. But these changes are not reflected in the web browser even after clearing browser cache and using an incognito window.

Every time there's a change in the code, I have to restarting the containers but this is not the right way to do.

when I start a shell session on the container and check its content it is updated as seen in the snapshot

[image]

but in the web browser even after reload is not updated as seen the the following snapshot

[image]

I also added nodemon as dependency in package.json for hot reload as seen below

**package.json**

```
 "scripts": {
    "db:up": "migrate-mongo up",
    "start": "nodemon --ignore './tests' index.js",
    "test": "jest --watchAll --colors"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.11.13"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "migrate-mongo": "^8.1.4",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7",
    "supertest": "^6.1.3"
  },
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:14.16.0-alpine3.13

RUN addgroup app && adduser -S -G app app
USER app

WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . . 

EXPOSE 3001 

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
---
services:
  web:
    build: ./frontend
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
  api:
    build: ./backend
    ports:
      - 3001:3001
    environment:
      DB_URL: mongodb://db/vidly
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/app
      - /app/node_modules
    command: ./docker-entrypoint.sh
  db:
    image: mongo:4.0-xenial
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - vidly:/data/db
volumes: 
  vidly:
```

Comment: Your `- /app/node_modules` entry seems to be missing a destination directory, like `- /app/node_modules:/somepath...`, or am i no seeing something ?

Comment: @Peterrabbit That is to exclude the node_modules from mounting the volume because it is installed when build the image. The app is worked fine and the source code in the container is updated based on the changed on the host. but to see the updated code it needs to restart the container.

Comment: Can you see in the logs of the api container if nodemon detects that the file has changed?

Comment: Also, I'm a little confused that the file you edit is called `/app/routes/index.js`. I would think that the file that node runs would be `/app/index.js`.

Comment: @HansKilian    nodemon is started but not detects the change.  ```routes/index.js``` is included in the ```/app/app.js``` as  ```const homeRoutes = require("./routes/index");```.